# Difference of leining between Israel and Chutz Laaretz in 5779

Tags: calendar, torah-reading, eretz-yisrael, chutz-laaretz

As anyone may know, because the last day of Pesach in chutz laarets fall out on Shabbat we read the special parsha for the 8th day of Pesach while in Israel since it wasn't Pesach anymore, they read Parshat Acharei Mot. This year, Israel and Chutz Laaretz will have to wait until Shabbat Devarim to read the same portion: the week before in Chutz Laaretz we will be reading Matot and Masei together while in Israel they will be leining Parshat Masei.

My question is why did our Sages make us wait so long this year - until Matot-Masei - to read a double Parsha and catch up the Israelis leining and not doing it earlier with other potential double Parshiot as Acharei Mot-Kedoshim or Behar-Bechukotay or Chukat-Balak?

Comment: One of the answers in the linked question is mine. You may be interested in reading parts of www.hakirah.org/Vol%202%20Epstein.pdf. I refer to it frequently. It's long and thorough, but it explains the origins and rules very well. Have patience going through it, and you need not read all of it to get the idea.